# Magento: Call template phtml file via Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, magento

I'm attempting to call a phtml file from Ajax on the homepage of my Magento site. I basically created a copy of app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml and customized it to view a particular category. If I add a block pointing to this file in the CMS section, I can view it just fine. However, I want to call this file via Ajax.

I followed the instructions to create a module [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch/), and then I attempted to follow the logic of Ajax in Magento by following [this post](http://subesh.com.np/2009/11/working-with-ajax-in-magento/). However, in the last step it lists:

`<module_controller_action>

  <block type="module/block"  name="root" output="toHtml"  template="module/template.phtml"/>

</module_controller_action>`

Where do I insert this? Also, for the `template="module/template.phtml"`, what folder is that referring to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That bit of XML needs to be put in a layout XML file, which is found in the

> app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/

directory. You can update any of the layout files with that snippit, but I don't recommend that.  I usually recommend creating a local.xml file in your template's layout directory

> app/design/frontend/*/*/layout/local.xml

Now, make sure you update the xml snippit too so that it says your real module, controller, and action name! :)

The `template="module/template.phtml"` will also need to be customized to reflect the path to the phtml file.  So if you put your custom phtml file in

> app/design/frontend/*/*/template/myfolder/myphtml.phtml

, then the code would be `template="myfolder/myphtml.phtml"`