# Magento: Rendering blank page when calling template from Ajax

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

First off, I must apologize for my lack of knowledge on the subject. I'm still new to Magento, and with the information I've come across, I should've been able to get this working. I started off [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081844/magento-call-template-phtml-file-via-ajax). I'm able to get the Ajax method to make a call, but I'm getting a blank 2column-left.phtml as my output (So I'm seeing the header, left column, blank main column, and footer). I have my files set up as so:

app/local/MyModule/Featured/Block/Featured.php

```
<?php  
class MyModule_Featured_Block_Featured extends Mage_Core_Block_Template  
{  
    public function __construct()  
    {  
        $this->_controller = 'featured';  
        $this->_blockGroup = 'featured';  
        parent::__construct();  
    }  
}  
?>
```

app/local/MyModule/Featured/controllers/FeaturedController.php

```
<?php 
class MyModule_Featured_FeaturedController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function displayAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

app/local/MyModule/Featured/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_Featured>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MyModule_Featured>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <featured>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MyModule_Featured</module>
                    <frontName>featured</frontName>
                </args>
            </featured>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

app/design/frontend/default/myLayout/layout/local.xml

```
<config>
    <featured_featured_display>
        <block type="module/block" name="root" output="toHtml" template="catalog/product/featured.phtml" />
    </featured_featured_display>
</config>
```

Ajax Code on Homepage custom phtml:

```
var url = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('featured/featured/display') ;?>";
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#featured-products').load(url);
});
```

Comment: Add Layout declaration inside `<frontend>` tags:
`<layout>
   <updates>
      <module_name module="module_name">
         <file>your_directory/layout.xml</file>
       </module_name>
   </updates>
</layout>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the layout file's root node should be `<layout>` and not `<config>`.

<sub>P.S.

If you wanted to do without jQuery - to avoid bloat - Magento already has [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) as standard and can do exactly the same.</sub>

```
var url = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('featured/featured/display') ?>";
document.observer('dom:loaded', function(){
    new Ajax.Updater('featured-products', url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the head's up on the Prototype syntax! Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same output after changing config to layout.

Answer (score 0):

Load layout includes the default handle normally, so my guess is that your assignment has no effect because there is a root note being loaded already. Try removing the root node first, and then add it back as your only node.